# Unexplainable "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Here is a sequence of very simple sql queries (MySQl 8.0)

```
drop table IF EXISTS stack_Compare;
drop table IF EXISTS lastNode;

CREATE TABLE stack_Compare (Station VARCHAR(20), Track INT);
CREATE TABLE lastNode (Last_Station_ID INT, I INT);

AlTER table lastNode ADD PRimary key (I);
INSERT INTO lastNode VALUES (1, 1);
Drop trigger IF EXISTS lastAdded;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER lastAdded AFTER INSERT
ON stack_Compare FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE lastNode SET Last_Station_ID = (SELECT Station.Station_ID FROM Station, stack_Compare WHERE New.Station = Station.Name) WHERE I = 1;
END $$


DELIMITER ;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertStation;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertMain;

DELIMITER $$

SET max_sp_recursion_depth=3;
CREATE PROCEDURE insertStation (insertstationID INT, starter VARCHAR(20), destination VARCHAR(20)) 
this_procedure:BEGIN

DECLARE nextNode INT DEFAULT NULL;
INSERT INTO stack_Compare (Station)
    SELECT Name from Station WHERE Station_ID = insertstationID;

IF insertStationID IN (SELECT Station_ID FROM Station WHERE Name = destination)
    THEN LEAVE this_procedure;
END IF;
SET nextNode = (SELECT Next_Station FROM Station WHERE Station_ID = insertstationID);
IF nextNode IS NULL
    THEN LEAVE this_procedure;
END IF;
IF nextNode = -1
    THEN LEAVE this_procedure;
ELSE CALL insertStation (nextNode, starter, destination);
END IF;
END
$$

CREATE PROCEDURE insertMain (starter VARCHAR(20), destination VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE nextNode INT DEFAULT NULL;
CALL insertStation(8, starter, destination);
loop1: LOOP
SET nextNode = (SELECT Station.Next_Station FROM Station, lastNode WHERE Station.Station_ID = lastNode.Last_Station_ID);
IF nextNode IN (SELECT Station_ID FROM Station WHERE Name = destination)
    THEN LEAVE loop1;
END IF;
END LOOP loop1;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL insertMain('G1','RG');

SELECT * FROM stack_Compare;

select * from lastNode;
```

and the station table is

[image]

So basically the query `SELECT * FROM stackCompare` should give

```
Station
G2
RG
```

But it only shows `G2` in there and the error is `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Which I am unable to find WHY from past few hours and a big project is stuck because of this. I guess after doing many experiments that there can be a problem with the `Set nextNode` line.

below are the queries to create and fill table.

```
CREATE TABLE Station (
    Station_ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    Line_ID INT,
    Prev_Station INT,
    Next_Station INT,
    Hybrid_ID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Station_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Line_ID) REFERENCES Line(Line_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Hybrid_ID) REFERENCES Hybrid(Hybrid_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE Station ADD FOREIGN KEY (Prev_Station) REFERENCES Station(Station_ID);
ALTER TABLE Station ADD FOREIGN KEY (Next_Station) REFERENCES Station(Station_ID);

INSERT INTO Station VALUES
    (1,'R1',1,NULL,2,NULL),
    (2,'R2',1,1,3,NULL),
    (3,'RG',1,-1,-1,1),
    (4,'RY',1,-1,-1,2),
    (5,'R3',1,4,6,NULL),
    (6,'R4',1,5,NULL,NULL),
    (7,'G1',3,NULL,8,NULL),
    (8,'G2',3,7,3,NULL),
    (9,'Y1',2,NULL,4,NULL),
    (10,'Y2',2,4,11,NULL),
    (11,'Y3',2,10,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: *`SET nextNode = (SELECT Next_Station FROM Station WHERE Station_ID = 8);`* may return a lot of rows which cannot be assigned into single variable.

Comment: Use recursive CTE instead of recursive iterations.

Comment: Something is wrong with the code you have posted.  You create stack_Compare with just one field station, but you are attempting to insert track as well.  Please edit your question so that the problem is reproducible.  (When I made changes to the SQL, it ran as expected).

Comment: @Akina But as you can see in schema that is not the case and even adding `LIMIT 1` doesn't help

Comment: Provide some sample data (CREATE TABLE for all tables, INSERT INTO with sample values), and desired data state after procedure execution.

Comment: Using the data provided (ie with just three entries in station), your code works (except for moving the SET max outside the delimeter).  Please provide enough data, so that we can repeat the problem.

Comment: Yes.  Please try creating a small test database with just these two tables and three records in station.  Check that the problem still occurs.  Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @mr.loop . . . The error seems really clear.  If you want to fix it, though, you should ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Akina can you put the recursive cte implementation as an answer

Comment: You add sample source table, but I do not see desired result... moreover, I do not see the task description itself.

Comment: Have you created a small database to check with the example data, that you get the error, because I don't?

Comment: @Akina sorry edited again and this time the problem is reproducible

Comment: @JonathanWillcock edited. this is the complete form of problem with nothing hidden. sorry for hiding this many details.

Comment: Your trigger is causing the problem the FROM doesn't need , stack_Compare.  Making that change I now get an infinite loop in insertMain, but at least the expected two values have been inserted in stack_Compare.  I leave it to you to figure out why your loop does not break!!!!

Comment: @JonathanWillcock thanks. I solved the problems in the queries. will add an answer.